# CodeIgniter to run from a subdirectory of another codeigniter installation

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to find a way to run codeigniter from a sub-directory of another codeigniter installation. The CI from the sub-directory would be for testing and the main one is the live site. Anyone could advice on this or any other better approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can just place this in the root folder and set the base url in the config :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/testsite/';
```

then it works. 
There can be issues with the first application serving the 404 pages when a route is not matched however

Comment: Thank you, I have set that, now he problem is that all he links inside the application are started with a / and that sends them to root http://www.example.com/url/to/something instead of http://www.example.com/testsite/url/to/something. Do you know if its a way to rewrite all links inside the folder to stay in that folder without modifying all over app ? I been searching for a httaccess solution but I haven't hit any usefull..

Comment: I would probably set the base href meta tag to base_url  so in the head : 
<base href="<?php echo base_url();?>"/>

Comment: Hi @Oliverb where do I have to set that? on each file/controller/model?

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the answer here, because is too long to use it as a comment...

I made it thru another approach: setting different $active_group in the config/database.php file.

So, first I have checked for a parameter in $_GET, if that is set we use a group, otherwise the default group (the other group is used for testing - a separate database, exact structure but without touching the main db)

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}

if (isset($_GET["debugmode"])){
    $active_group = 'demodb';
    $active_record = TRUE;
    $_SESSION['debugmode'] = true;
}elseif (isset($_SESSION["debugmode"])){
    $active_group = 'demodb';
    $active_record = TRUE;
}elseif(!isset($_GET["debugmode"]) && !isset($_SESSION["debugmode"])){
    $active_group = 'default';
    $active_record = TRUE;
}
```

To make sure this will work on all the controllers /views, because we wont have that $_GET parameter all over the application, we can set that session value once we have that $_GET parameter present. Also, we have to make sure we destroy that session when we log out or after an amount of time.

Reason of using a Session value: by default CI is using that table to store the sessions, without using our session value, it will force somehow to use the default DB, or at least I couldn't find it to trick this step.